# why is my custom extended colors in tailwind css not working

Tags: tailwind-css

I added custom colors to my tailwind config files in the extended section and used them to style my element but it doesn't seem to be working. When i look at the code preview everything seems to be fine but the styles are not displaying on the browser.

This is what my config looks like:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./index.html"],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors : {
        zimaBlu:"#50f2ac"
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

the html

Hello world!

Comment: please post your config and any other relevant code.